# Java/Android unexplained compile error: is not abstract and does not override abstract method onTabReselected(Tab,FragmentTransaction) in TabListener

Tags: java, android, interface, abstract

I'm trying to implement a swipable tab view in android, following the developer guide [here](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html#), butI am getting a compile error rejecting my custom TabListener:

```
[javac] /home/brad/Other/code/Prayson/Prayson/src/net/bradmont/prayson/Main.java:73: error: Main.HomeTabListener is not abstract and does not override abstract method onTabReselected(Tab,FragmentTransaction) in TabListener
[javac]     private class HomeTabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
```

However, I *am* overriding onTabReselected, here is the class definition:

```
private class HomeTabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    public void onTabReselected (ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        return; // I added this thinking a non-empty function would do something
    }

    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        mPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    }

}
```

I've tried copying & pasting the function definition from the API docs, I've tried using an inline definition (new ActionBar.TabListener { ..). I'm sure this has to be something simple, but I haven't a clue.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Use the `@Override` annotation to show where you're *trying* to override/implement a method - that should make it clearer if there are typos etc.

Comment: Doing so gives me this error for all three methods:
    [javac] /home/brad/Other/code/Prayson/Prayson/src/net/bradmont/prayson/Main.java:86: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype

Comment: Okay, well that's a start. Do you have your own types called `ActionBar` or `FragmentTransaction` by any chance? What happens if you fully-qualify the type names?

Comment: My guess is that you are mixing the support and non-support versions of `ActionBar.Tab` and `FragmentTransaction`. Make sure that all your imports reference either the versions of these in the support library or the ones outside the support library.

Comment: @Tanis.7x thanks, that was the problem. I was using the v4 FragmentTransaction and Android.app.ActionBar. I can't seem to find ActionBar in the support.v4 (only v7), is it there? I don't have any old devices to test on; will using the non-support ActionBar cause any problems?

Comment: [The ActionBar only exists in v7](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/features.html). If your minsdk is above API 14, you shouldn't have any issues. However, you will likely encounter issues if you support anything below 14.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Tanis.7x suggested, I was mixing FragmentTransaction from support.v4 and ActionBar.Tab from native. Switching to android.app.FragmentTransaction fixed the problem.